# How can I delete every node_modules folder using a npm script?

Tags: powershell, npm, node-modules, npm-scripts

In my project I have multiple node_module directories that get generated with many of them are in child components. I would like to be able to run a npm command to delete every single one.

Here's is my attempt in the parent package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
       "clean": "powershell.exe -Command \"Get-ChildItem -Path node_modules -Force -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse\""
   },
```

This doesn't work as it will remove the parent node_modules but none of the nested child ones.

I am using windows powershell to execute the command `npm run clean`

Comment: A conceptually cleaner command would be `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath ./node_modules -Directory -Filter node_modules -Force -Recurse`, but it's not clear to me why your command would try to remove the top-level `node_modules`.